# Universal nested get/set for trees in Python

Tags: python, tree, hash-map

Based on [this source](https://github.com/habnabit/passacre/blob/9411c639dfd44c19680e497727488edcafae0c70/passacre/util.py#L72-L82), I've made the following universal get / set function, to make it possible to work on OrderedDict trees for example.

```
def nested_expand_and_get(d, keys):
    intermediate = d
    for key in keys:
        intermediate = intermediate.setdefault(key, d.__class__())
    return intermediate


def nested_set(d, keys, value):
    intermediate = nested_expand_and_get(d, keys[:-1])
    intermediate[keys[-1]] = value
```

I've tested it on some examples I could come up with, but I'm not sure in two things:

1. I've simplified quite a bit from the linked source, namely, I'm not using lambdas and I've removed the if line.
2. I've also introduced the tree type auto-detection, which I believe should work well for uniform trees.

Is this function correct as long as the given tree is uniform (by which I mean that it only contains all dict or OrderedDict or etc. elements)?
Would you recommend using something else for working on ordered trees (without external libs)?